# 'module' object has no attribute 'WriteToBigQuery' when running Apache Beam on Google App Engine Flex

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a Google App Engine triggering a Cloud DataFlow pipeline. This pipeline is supposed to write the final PCollection to Google BigQuery, but I can't find a way to install the right apache_beam.io dependency.

I'm running Apache Beam version 2.2.0 locally.

The project structure follows the code from [this blog post](http://zablo.net/blog/post/python-apache-beam-google-dataflow-cron).

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
"WriteToBigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            ("%s:%s.%s" % (PROJECT, DATASET, TABLE)),
            schema=TABLE_SCHEMA,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
        )
```

When I run this code locally, the `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery()` is called correctly. It is fetched from the `apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py` from my virtual environment.

But I can't install this dependency on my `lib` folder that is shipped with the app on deploy.

Even though I have a requirements file containing `apache-beam[gcp]==2.2.0` as a requirement, when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt -t lib`, the `apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py` that is downloaded to my `lib` folder does not contain the class `WriteToBigQuery`, and then I get the error `'module' object has no attribute 'WriteToBigQuery'` when running the app on Google App Engine.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can get the right `bigquery.py`?

Comment: Are you running this on App Engine, rather than DataFlow?

Comment: What version of Beam do you have installed?

Comment: @Maximilian, the pipeline is run on DataFlow, but it's being triggered from an App Engine instance [like on this project](https://github.com/marrrcin/python-beam-dataflow-cron). And I'm using Apache Beam 2.2.0. Thanks!

Comment: That's v weird. I see that class clearly in `apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py`. What do you see in that file?

Answer (score 0):

It is not immediately obvious, but to run in App Engine, as mentioned in the [blog post](https://zablo.net/blog/post/python-apache-beam-google-dataflow-cron/index.html#deploying-python-dataflow-pipeline-to-google-app-engine) it is necessary to create a `setup.py` (even if you already have a `requirements.txt`), and point to it via the `--setup_file ./setup.py` command line option when running the pipeline.